# Chrome inspect not showing android application WebView anymore for debugging

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have created an application in an Ionic capacitor. Now it's running in android mobile perfectly, but I want to debug its webview. Previously It used to display the android application in the list whenever I used to connect via USB Debugging mode and open the URL (`chrome://inspect`) in chrome but since a few months back it's not showing me my android application in chrome debugging inspect. I tried various given solutions on the internet like below also, but I did not get any result and solution, still waiting for a solution.

FYI, It shows the mobile chrome browser tabs whenever I open chrome on mobile but not my debugging application.
Please help me, I really need to debug my application's webview.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
  { 
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); 
  }
}
```

[image: This is the inspect page screenshot.]

This is the inspect page screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, I have got the solution for that. I don't know why the google chrome updated version is not working with google inspect devices but. Yes, reset my android phone and it again showed my android webview in the [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices) URL. by finding several more pages and google searches. I found somewhere that the new version of google chrome on your mobile phone is not working to debug android webview. For the time I have downgraded my google chrome versions to "version 86" and below and it again started showing the android webview.
Thank you

Comment: If this solution solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.